# Java apache.HttpClient Keep-alive

Tags: java, apache, rest

I've spent the last several hours trying to figure this question out. I've run out of ideas of what to search for help.

Im using a REST API with apache httpclient. The api has a 2 connections/sec limit and 15 requests/second.

Does anyone know a better way of limiting requests to a certain number or know what I am doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

the response im getting back is :

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag:
"6916f565d802d2220ed6b3628d142225db985cc0"
Date:
Wed, 01 Jun 2016 02:34:01 GMT
Content-Length:
264
Expires:
Thu, 02 Jun 2016 02:34:01 GMT
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
Server:
openresty/1.7.0.1

{
"instruments":  [
 {
  "instrument": "AUD_CAD",
  "displayName": "AUD/CAD",
  "pip": "0.0001",
  "maxTradeUnits": 10000000
},
 {
  "instrument": "AUD_CHF",
  "displayName": "AUD/CHF",
  "pip": "0.0001",
  "maxTradeUnits": 10000000
}
 ]
 }
```

It has Connection:keep-alive. No matter what I do it remakes the connection even though HttpClient is by default persistent. Is there a way to send a request without creating a new connection.

my implementation looks like this:

//**Main**

```
    main(String[] args){

Queline que = new Queline(1);

      String test1 = "no";
    for(int i = 0; i < 1;i++){

    while(test1 == "no"){
        String function1 = que.function1(settings); 
        if(function1 == "no"){
            System.out.println("Waiting too many requests");

        }
}
```

//**Queline (throttle class)** - the if/else is used to throttle requests which is monitored by a thread resetting RequestNo, 1 second after request is sent

```
 public String function1(AccountSettings settings) throws IOException{


    System.out.println("RequestNo= " + queSync.REQUESTNO + " Max = " +     queSync.MAXREQUESTS );

    if(queSync.REQUESTNO <= MAXREQUESTS){
        //fire request
        String responseJSON = orHelper.getResponseJSON(path, settings);
        return "RAN";
    }
    else{
        //if null calling function must wait
        System.out.println("RequestNo= " + queSync.REQUESTNO + " Max = " + queSync.MAXREQUESTS );
        return "no";

    }

       }
```

//**orHelper class getResponseJson function**  - sends HttpGet

```
property:`HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`


public String getResponseJSON(String path, AccountSettings settings) throws   IOException{
String accessToken = "";
    String accountID = "";
    String accountName = "";



    if(settings != null){

        accessToken = settings.getToken();
        accountID = settings.getAccountID();
        accountName = settings.getAccountName();
   }

       HttpUriRequest httpGet = new HttpGet(path);

        httpGet.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken));
        httpGet.setHeader(new BasicHeader("connection", "keep-alive" ));


        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


    String response= parseEntityJSON(resp);
        System.out.println(response);

    return response;
    }
```

//parseEntityJSON looks like this inside above class

```
      public String parseEntityJSON(HttpResponse resp) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

    for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
     }

    return builder.toString();

     }
```

Comment: There is no evidence here that it is creating a new connection.